# Google Chart height cannot be increased

Tags: html, css, google-visualization

I have this Google Chart (Line Graph) code:

```
<html>
<head>

  <style>
    .chart {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      min-height: 500px;
    }

    #chart {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      min-height: 500px;
    }

  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">

    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    window.addEventListener('resize', function (event) {
      drawChart();
    });

    function drawChart() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('number', 'Day');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Guardians of the Galaxy');
      data.addColumn('number', 'The Avengers');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Transformers: Age of Extinction');

      data.addRows([
        [1,  37.8, 80.8, 41.8],
        [2,  30.9, 69.5, 32.4],
        [3,  25.4,   57, 25.7],
        [4,  11.7, 18.8, 10.5],
        [5,  11.9, 17.6, 10.4],
        [6,   8.8, 13.6,  7.7],
        [7,   7.6, 12.3,  9.6],
        [8,  12.3, 29.2, 10.6],
        [9,  16.9, 42.9, 14.8],
        [10, 12.8, 30.9, 11.6],
        [11,  5.3,  7.9,  4.7],
        [12,  6.6,  8.4,  5.2],
        [13,  4.8,  6.3,  3.6],
        [14,  4.2,  6.2,  3.4]
      ]);

      var options = {
        chart: {
          title: 'Box Office Earnings in First Two Weeks of Opening',
          subtitle: 'in millions of dollars (USD)'
        },
        // width: 1800,
        // height: 1000,
        axes: {
          x: {
            0: {side: 'top'}
          }
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('line_top_x'));
      chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
    }


  </script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="line_top_x"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

you can write that to a file and just open it with a browser - it renders fine, but I cannot get the height of the graph to increase no matter what I add to the css (the style tag).

Anyone know how to get the height to be 100% of the page?

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot, the graph is squashed where the height is only about 100px.

I added the following CSS:

```
body {
  width:80%;
  height:80%;
  margin:10% auto;
  background:#e6e6e6;
}

#chart_wrap {
  border:1px solid gray;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  height: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

#chart {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

and I still cannot get the height to increase:

[image]

I think I need to use this to alter the width/height

```
     var options = {
        chart: {
          title: 'Node.js memory usage (RSS, Heap Used, Heap Total)',
          subtitle: '(In megabytes.)'
        },
        // width: 1800,
        // height: 1000,
        axes: {
          x: {
            0: {side: 'top'}
          }
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('line_top_x'));
      chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
```

but I don't know what to use for height/width to make it 100% of the window/container.

Comment: you can use chart options --> `height: '100%', width: '100%'` -- which will be relative to the container -- the chart will need to be redrawn when the size of the container changes...

Comment: thanks, I swear I tried that, but will try it again, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

add this css

```
#line_top_x {
    height: 100vh;
}
```